# How to use BibTex correctly

Tags: bibtex

I've tried to write this into a `.tex` file and in the same folder in which this file is put, I've added a `bibli.text` file.

.tex file's code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}


\begin{document}

J'insère le premier \cite{Uml}.

\bibliography{bibli} % mon fichier de base de données s'appelle bibli.bib

\end{document}
```

bibli.bib file's code :

```
@book{Uml,
    author    = {P. Roques et F. Vallée},
    title     = {De l’analyse des besoins à la conception},
    journal = {UML en action},
    edition  = {Quatrième},
    publisher = {Eyrolles},
    date      = {01/03/2007},
    location   = {France},
    pages     = {381},
    }
```

To build this, I've :

- compiled for 2 times.
- Build > BibTex.
- compiled for 2 times.

*OS : Windows*

**Edit :** That in the the `Outline` the full structure of the BibTex file is putted by the compiler.
I've no error message while compiling but The bibliography written into my bibli.tex is not included in the pdf file result.

Comment: You're surely missing a `\bibliographystyle` command; try adding `\bibliographystyle{plain}` before `\bibliography{bibli}`

Comment: I've not error message while compiling but The bibliography written into my `bibli.tex` is not included in the pdf file result.

Comment: What does the bibli.blg say (this is the .log file for bibtex)?

Comment: Regardless of the problem I'd advise to migrate to »[biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)« and Biber as back-end.

Comment: @Bernard, I'ven't found that file in the folder in which bibli.tex is putted.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig, Can you please write a full example ?

Comment: It may happen (depending on your system) that  all auxiliary files are stored in a TeXaux subdirectory. You *must* have a .blg  and a .bbl files. You also must add in your preamble a `\bibliographystyle{...}`command. Is the extension of your bibliography file `.bib`?

Comment: @Bernard, [here is my full folder contents](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nUCgF.png). The file that I'm compiling from is `New Text Document.tex`

Comment: @egreg, Thank you very much !!! You was right !!!!!!!

Comment: @user9289501: the presence of a .bcf and a .run.xml shows that, at some moment, you've launched biber, and not bibtex. While this is recommended (especially for the problem of accented letters), you must load `biblatex`, add in your preammble `\addbibresource{bibli.bib}` (with the extension) and in your main text write `printbibliography`rather than `\bibliography{bibli}`.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, doing that triggred these errors, can you please help me to resolve these ? `I found no \citation commands---while reading file xxx.aux, I found no \bibdata command---while reading file xxx.aux, I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file xxx.aux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A migration to »[biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)« with Biber as back-end is suggestive. That would also solve the language issue in the bibliography items. Note that you have to do the corresponding settings in your editor in order to make it run Biber instead of BibTeX (or run Biber manually).

```
\documentclass[11pt,francais]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  agrave={à},
  eacute={é}
}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{uml,
  author    = {P. Roques and F. Vallée},
  title     = {De l’analyse des besoins à la conception},
  journal   = {UML en action},
  edition   = {4},
  publisher = {Eyrolles},
  date      = {2007-03-01},
  location  = {France},
  pages     = {381}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  J'insère le premier \cite{uml}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `date` field of the database entry has been reformatted in order to comply the demands. Further customization of the bibliography style is of course possible.

---

[image]

Comment: The »[filecontents](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)« package and its corresponding `filecontents*` environment are only used here to make the example self-contained. They should not appear in the actual document.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, this wouldn't work, [here is the pdf file result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AAenJ.png)

Comment: @user3289501: Obviously it works (for me). You seem to do something wrong. Did you run Biber correctly? Do you get error messages or warnings? Do you have an up-to-date TeX system?

Comment: How do I to download Biber, please ?

Comment: @user3289501: It should be part of your TeX system. Hence no need for download.

Comment: Then how to run it, please ?

Comment: The same as BibTeX. As already mentioned, you may need to modify the settings of your editor or run Biber manually on the command line. See the comment of Bernard to your question.

Comment: I've got this error while running Biber `ERROR - Cannot find control file 'C:\Users\Nectarys\Desktop\Newfolder\ok.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?` (I've just pasted into that `ok.tex` file your code)

Comment: I can only tell you that Biber should search for `ok.bcf`, but somehow it searches for `ok.tex.bcf`. So I can only speculate that your Biber call is not correct due to faulty settings.

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles perfectly for me. Note that I encoded everything in utf8, including the.bib file, as Biber understands this encoding. If you use `JabRef` to write your database, you can ask it thatsave  in utf8 format.

I also corrected some of the field: the entry is book, and the `journal` field has no meaning. Actually UML 2 in action is the (main) title and  "De l’analyse des besoins à la conception" is the `subtitle`. Also the format of the date field is `yyyy-mm-dd` (with hyphens, not slashes – as must be written in french, btw); but I think it's irrelevant for a book, and I replaced it with the `year`field. I gave first names in full, should you change your mind for their formatting; the `firstinits` option takes care of printing the short form.

Main file code:

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

```
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage[francais]{babel}

        \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
        \usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric, firstinits]{biblatex}
        \addbibresource{bibli.bib}

        \begin{document}

        J'insère le premier \cite{Uml}.

        \printbibliography

        \end{document}
```

.bib code:

```
        % This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
        % Encoding: UTF8

        @BOOK{Uml,
          title = {UML 2 en action},
          publisher = {Eyrolles},
          year = {2007},
          author = {Roques, Pascal and  Vallée,  Franck},
          pages = {381},
          edition = {4},
          location = {France},
          subtitle = {De l’analyse des besoins à la conception}
        }
```

[image]